# Diagram of Riemann Surface for $\sqrt {z^2-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm trying to discuss what $\sqrt {z^2-1}$ looks like. I'm trying to relate it to the square root function $z \mapsto \sqrt z$ but not getting anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's a sphere. Take $\mathbb C$ and cut a slit between $-1$ and $1$. The surface has two sheets of this form, so gluing them together along this slit and compactifying gives a sphere.